# Trying to get my ROR site up and running...getting a 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

running a R.o.R. site on passenger. Passenger is running fine, but I'm not sure if I am having an issue with the way I setup my vHosts or what, but It's returning a the apache start page, and not my application.

When I run

```
passenger-status
```

here is the message:

```
Version : 4.0.18
Date    : 2013-09-26 10:42:03 -0400
Instance: 20958
----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
Processes     : 0
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
[USERNAME@gregorymurray relaunchradio]#
```

Here is the passenger stuff in my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-    4.0.18/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.18
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby
PassengerDefaultUser root
```

No problem that I see there, here is my vhost.conf file in the main directory of my site:

```
ServerName gregorymurray.com
ServerAlias gregorymurray.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/gregorymurray.com/relaunchradio/public
PassengerAppRoot /var/www/vhosts/gregorymurray.com/relaunchradio

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/gregorymurray.com/relaunchradio/public">
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

RailsEnv production
RailsBaseURI /
```

Here are the two links I followed in the process of getting this running:

http://www.twohard.com/blog/setting-rails-passenger-mediatemple-dv35-servers

https://coderwall.com/p/lu3nfa

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure apache2 is finding the vhost.conf file? Are you using some kind of shared hosting that requires placing that file in your website's main directory? Because, that's not the normal setup. The virtual hosts file belongs under /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd depending on whether using Ubuntu or centOS. Look at your apache conf file to find out where it's looking for the virtual hosts.

Open /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and look for vhost.conf. Or look for a Include directive of the full path to your gregorymurray.com. I doubt either one will be found. Which means you need to move vhost.conf to /etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/vhost.conf and add Include sites-enabled/ in your httpd.conf just above the passenger module stuff.

Placing your vhost.conf in your website directory would require that you alter your httpd.conf to look in that website directory for a virtual host conf file. That's not the default setup or conventional setup.

Comment: Yes, I'm on CentOS, using a VPS. The apache conf file is located at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and the vhost.conf file is located in the site directory: /var/www/vhosts/gregorymurray.com This is what worked for me on my personal server through Media Temple, but I'm trying to setup on my clients server through MT and im having all these problems....

Comment: Open /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and look for vhost.conf. Or look for a Include directive of your gregorymurray.com. I doubt either one will be found. Which means you need to move vhost.conf to /etc/httpd/conf/sites-enabled/vhost.conf and add Include sites-enabled/ in your httpd.conf just above the passenger module stuff.